# Transfer source structure to target structure using parts of the file and folder names (only numbers)

Tags: loops, batch-file

I would like to automate an almost daily task of folder and file sorting with a batch.

I can't get any further than the code I've submitted here.

Here is a picture of what should happen here.

[image: https://postimg.cc/N5ZVhpZF]

From the source, folders and any subfolders, are to be created in the target directory on the basis of the numbers in the pdf files, (in order to then copy files from the source structure into the target structure). This works quite well, but it also creates a `p-folder` from the `C-P****` files, which I don't need. I also don't need the `E***` files and no folder with them.  I.e. I only need numbers.

But it also happens that there are serial numbers in the `test` or `pre-test` folder where I don't have any PDFs, but I still need folders in the target structure and the `E_PS-***` folders have to be copied over too.

Finally, all the new serial number folders have to be copied to a separate target path and the `Documents,` `Pre-Test` and `Test` folders have to be deleted from the source path.

I would be very grateful for any tips and help!

```bash
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set source and destination paths
set "quelle=Quelle"
set "ziel=Ziel"

REM Datum abfragen
set /p date="Datum des Ordners eingeben (yyyymmdd): "

REM Schleife um Ordner zu ermitteln und diese dann zu verarbeiten im quellverzeichnis
for /d %%A in ("%quelle%\%date%_*") do (
    REM Dateien nach SN gruppieren 
    for %%B in ("%%A\Dokumente\*.pdf") do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%C in ("%%~nB") do (
            REM Ordner und Subordner nach SN erstellen 
            set "destination=ziel\%%C"
            if not exist "!destination!" ( 
                mkdir "!destination!"
            )
            for %%D in (Aida64_Log Gauging Production Project Service) do mkdir "!destination!\%%D"
            for %%E in (Calibration Pre-Calibration) do mkdir "!destination!\Gauging\%%E"
            for %%F in (Fokussierung Lidartest Reparatur Straßentest) do mkdir "!destination!\Service\%%F"
            REM Kopiert Fehlerreport/PCL/ Servicebericht in Ordner Reparatur
            copy "%%B" "!destination!\Service\Reparatur\" /y
            REM neue Schleife fürs kopieren von Vorprüfung und Prüfungsberichte

            REM Copy matching subfolders to destination
            for /d %%G in ("%%A\Vorprüfungen\*%%C") do (
                robocopy "%%G" "!destination!\Gauging\Pre-Calibration" /e /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl /ndl /r:0 /w:0
    
                    for /d %%H in ("%%A\Prüfungsberichte\*%%C") do (
                        robocopy "%%H" "!destination!\Gauging\Calibration" /e /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl /ndl /r:0 /w:0
                    )
                )

            )
        )
    )

    REM Löscht die Startordner  
    REM rd /s /q "%%A"

    REM Pause nach Durchführung der Schleife
    pause
)

endlocal
```